# Display text property in toolstripbutton not enabled

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a toolstrip with two buttons (Accept and Cancel). When the toolstripbutton is not enabled I can't display the text property.
How can I show the text property in not enabled toolstripbutton in C#?

[image]

Comment: is it possible text color is same as background?

Comment: No. The color is the same that the Accept button (SystemColors.Control). Thanks!!

Comment: whats the background color?

Comment: does it not show up either say when you change it to red or blue or something

Comment: The ForeColor is SystemColors.ControlDarkDark. I tried to change the ForeColor in a blue, red colors and that colours does not display too.

Comment: Are you sure the DisplayStyle is "ImageAndText"  and Text is not empty?

Comment: Yes. The display stile is "ImageAndText" and Text is not empty. Thanks!!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Could you post any code you have so far?

Comment: can you change the background color and try

Comment: I change the background color of the toolstrip and the colour of the Text of disabled toolstripbutton is SystemColors.ControlDarkDark, the same of the background color of the toolStripbutton.

Comment: I change the backcolor of the ToolStrip and the text in a not enabled toolstripbutton is displayed. Thanks all!!